# SQL Only get top rank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to rank a users search terms and return only the most relevant searches.

Please see my query below.

```
SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                c.ContractorId,
                c.CompanyName,
                co.County,
                t.Town,
                s.[Service],
                s.ServiceId,

                CASE
                    WHEN c.CompanyName = @CompanyName THEN 1
                    WHEN ct.TownId = @TownId AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId THEN 1
                    WHEN cc.CountyId = @CountyId AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId THEN 1
                    WHEN cc.CountyId = @CountyId AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId THEN 1
                    WHEN ct.TownId = @TownId AND cc.CountyId = @CountyId THEN 2
                    WHEN ct.TownId IS NULL AND cc.CountyId IS NULL AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId THEN 3
                    WHEN @TownId IS NULL AND @CountyId IS NULL AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId THEN 3
                END AS 'Rank'

            FROM
                Contractors.Contractor c 
            LEFT JOIN
                Contractors.ContractorTown ct ON c.ContractorId = ct.ContractorId
            LEFT JOIN
                Geographical.Town t ON ct.TownId = t.TownId
            LEFT JOIN 
                Contractors.ContractorCounty cc ON c.ContractorId = cc.ContractorId
            LEFT JOIN
                Geographical.County co ON cc.CountyId = co.CountyId
            LEFT JOIN
                Contractors.ContractorService cs ON c.ContractorId = cs.ContractorId
            LEFT JOIN
                Contractors.[Service] s ON cs.ServiceId = s.ServiceId
            JOIN
                Contractors.ContractorLiability cl ON cl.ContractorId = c.ContractorId
            WHERE
                c.CompanyName = @CompanyName
                OR (ct.TownId = @TownId AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId)
                OR (cc.CountyId = @CountyId AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId)
                OR (ct.TownId = @TownId AND cc.CountyId = @CountyId)
                OR (ct.TownId IS NULL AND cc.CountyId IS NULL AND cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId)
                OR (cs.ServiceId = @ServiceId)) AS a
```

From this I am trying to only get the highest ranked results, for example:

If there is a rank 1, return all rows that are rank 1 only.
If there is a rank 2, return all rows that are rank 2 only.
Else return everything.

I am not sure the best way to tackle this - any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I would recommend that you start off with a completely different query, which only deals with one column of identifying information, and constructs a fake rank based on that column. (E.g, rank them according to `id % 3` or something) Then you (and we) would only see the complexity of the filtering problem, without the added complexity of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your final **WHERE** statement:

```
where...
...
and
case
when exists (select rank from table where rank=1) then rank=1
when exists (select rank from table where rank=2) then rank=2
else rank is not null
end
```

It should narrow the scope to only rows where rank=1 if any rows have a rank equal to 1, then does the same for 2 if there are none at 1. If no rows have a rank of 1 or 2, then it just makes sure that there is a value for rank.

Have you tried temporary tables?

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
ContractorId int,
    CompanyName varchar(255),
    County varchar(255),
    Town varchar(255),
    [Service] varchar(255),
    ServiceId int,
rank int
);
```

to establish the table, then

```
--REPLACE 'SELECT * FROM(' WITH
INSERT INTO #temp (ContractorId, CompanyName, County, Town, [Service], ServiceID, rank)
    SELECT 
            c.ContractorId,
            c.CompanyName,
            co.County,
            t.Town,
            s.[Service],
            s.ServiceId,
    ...
```

Then run another query on your new temp table.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see from the query above, I dont have a table to select the rank from.